# How to hide "duplicate" row values in SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a problem with SQL database in [Serposcope](https://serposcope.serphacker.com/). Basically what I'm trying to do is select all keywords with their rank and date. I managed to came up with something like this so far:

```
select keyword,
    rank,
    day
from GOOGLE_SEARCH
inner join GOOGLE_RANK on GOOGLE_SEARCH.id = GOOGLE_RANK.google_search_id
inner join RUN on GOOGLE_RANK.run_id = RUN.id
order by day;
```

and it gives me this result:

```
+-----------+------+------------+
| keyword   | rank | day        |
+-----------+------+------------+
| keyword1  |    4 | 2017-04-01 |
| keyword1  |    4 | 2017-04-02 |
+-----------+------+------------+
```

what I'm trying to do is to return in HTML something like this:

```
+-----------+------+------------+
| keyword   | rank | day        |
+-----------+------+------------+
| keyword1  |    4 | 2017-04-01 |
|           |    4 | 2017-04-02 |
+-----------+------+------------+
```

so the keywords don't duplicate. Could you give me a hint if I can do this staight from SQL or I need to hide them in HTML/PHP? I'm not a dev so please forgive me if I asked a trivial question.

Comment: You should definitely do this in your application code. SQL is not the right tool for this sort of manipulation.

Comment: You will need to do this in HTML/PHP.  SQL can group values together but not in this specific fashion where it leaves column values empty.

Comment: You should hide the keywords using php. Try making a map of keywords with keywords as keys in the map and while looping through the result populate the map. This way you will have a clean structure for generating the table in html.

Comment: Select distinct - sesrch in google

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to order them by the grouping row and then you can add other orderby columns:

```
order by keyword, day;
```

second, you need to skip the similar elements in your loop:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $last_keyword = null;
    // fetch associative array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row["keyword"] != $last_keyword){
             // print the changed keyword
             echo $row["keyword"];
             // set the last keyword to the new keyword
             $last_keyword = $row["keyword"];
        }
        // do your other listings here
    }

    // free result set
    $result->free();
}
```